# Karma and Jasmine installation without npm

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I want to use Karma and Jasmine to test my AngularJS application.  All of the documentation I've found to install Karma and Jasmine involve using npm.  I can't use npm because I am restricted, the reason doesn't matter.  So far I have pulled Jasmine and Karma from Github using zip files.  I want to add Karma and Jasmine to my project, but I don't think unzipping the entire contents of the respective GitHub repos is the way to go.

I'd like to know what I need to make Karma and Jasmine usable within my AngularJS project without using npm.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is possible, but will take a huuuuuge amount of work because of the dependencies. If you take a look at *karma*'s repository, you can find a file `package.json` ([here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/v0.13.0/package.json)). In this file there is a property `dependencies` ([link](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/v0.13.0/package.json#L208)), which lists the modules *karma* depends on. So you'll have to find their sources, manually download all of them with respective version number and put in the folder called `node_modules` created in the *karma* module folder. But each of these modules *karma* depends on also has dependencies listed in their own `package.json` - you'll have to download them too keeping in mind version numbers and putting them in module's `node_modules` folder. And this dependency nesting can be really really deep.

Some modules may have extra scripts to be executed after they have been installed ([scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)), which are called by *NPM* by default on installation. Maybe there are some other things which I am not aware of. Generally speaking it was designed to be installed via *NPM* and it's rarely the case when someone has no access to use it.

I would advise to ask somebody who has access to *NPM* to do an install of required packages and share the result of installation with you. Everything will be installed in the `node_modules` folder of the directory you run *NPM* commands from, it would be easy to do.

[Here](http://www95.zippyshare.com/v/e3OwmX4D/file.html) you can download version I've created, it has *karma v0.13.1*, *karma-jasmine v0.3.6* and *karma-chrome-launcher v0.2.0*. I hope it will work for you, because we might have different OS (mine is Ubuntu 14.04 x64), I'm not sure if *NPM* does something OS-specific while installation of any package.

You should place the content of the archive to your project directory, to execute tests from your project folder use a terminal command:

```
./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
```

I would still advise to solve the problem of accessing the *NPM* if you want to closely work with modules it stores.

Comment: Wow, that does sound pretty awful.  I was hoping I didn't have to do that.  I'm sure somebody has already done it.  Perhaps I need to sharpen my Googling skills to find a badass zip file or something of that nature.  Thanks for the helpful insight.